# Azure B2C: Adding an orchestration step to ask for more information

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm looking to break up our registration journey into multiple pages, so we don't end up with a massive form.

I'm trying to add an orchestration step after the initial registration page to ask for the user's favourite colour.

I have added the following claims provider:

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
        <DisplayName>Self Asserted</DisplayName>
        <TechnicalProfiles>
            <TechnicalProfile Id="SATP-GetFavouriteColour">
                <DisplayName>Local Account Sign In</DisplayName>
                <Protocol Name="Proprietary"
                          Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.signuporsignin</Item>
                </Metadata>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="favouriteColour" Required="true" />
                </OutputClaims>
                <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop"/>
            </TechnicalProfile>
        </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
```

and have updated my SignUpOrSignIn journey to include it just before the final step of returning the claims to the RP, like so:

```xml
 <OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="GetFavouriteColour" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SATP-GetFavouriteColour" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
```

I have also added the output claim to my Relying Party file like so:

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="favouriteColour" DefaultValue="Lemons"/>
```

The policy files validate and upload successfully, but when I go through the journey, I simply get the default value of "Lemons" returned to my RP.

I expected B2C to ask the user for their favourite colour. **Why isn't B2C asking the user for the new field I added**?

Am I right in thinking this is possible, and I'm just missing something simple?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the cause of this, I had missed off `<UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>` from my claimType declaration